# SQLITE, can't update a table because it keep thinking that the variable is a column

Tags: python, sqlite

this is my code emp is a table

```
def MiseAJour(pourc):
    cur.execute("update emp set salaire = salaire + salaire*pourc*0.01")
    conn.commit()
MiseAJour(10)
```

okay the problem is that it keeps thinking that `pourc` is a column while it's a variable is there anyway to avoid that, kept trying string formatting and it didn't work..
the error im getting:

> cur.execute("update emp set salaire = salaire + salaire*pourc*0.01")
>   sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: pourc"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a placeholder in the query string, and provide `pourc` as a parameter argument.

```
def MiseAJour(pourc):
    cur.execute("update emp set salaire = salaire + salaire * ? * 0.01", (pourc,))
    conn.commit()
```